# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'watch')

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

IN my NodeJS I want to watch a collection in MongoDB Atlas

```
const changeStream = collections_saga.createOrg.watch(pipeline);
```

results in **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'watch')**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.6",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "mongodb": "^4.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.8",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typedoc": "^0.22.10",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: Time for some basic debugging on your part.  Add a `console.log(collections_saga.createOrg)` to see what that is.  The error message makes it appear that is `undefined` and thus you get an error when trying to read the `.watch` property from that.  If it is indeed `undefined`, then back up in your code and figure out why it's `undefined`.  Since you show us only one line of code, there's nothing else we can advise other than do your own debugging to figure out why `collections_saga.createOrg` doesn't have the value it's supposed to.

Comment: I placed it outside of MongoClient connection
 - MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation. After replacing it in function where MongoClient is connected and changeStream is created